# Setting a hash of instance variables to a new variable to call .each_with_index on in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got three instance variables:

```
@book, @recent_books, @popular_books
```

@books contains 1 currently viewed record, @recent_books contains 10 records, and @popular_books contains 10 records

I want to assign a variable to them and put them into a hash together, so in my controller I've got:

```
@book_list = [@book, @recent_books, @popular_books]
```

Now in my view I want to iterate over each of them and display the information for each:

```
@book_list.each_with_index do |(book_list), index|
book_list.title,
book_list.author,
index + 1,
etc
```

The issue I've got is this only iterates over three records instead of 21. However if I check @book_list I can see all 21 records, but @book_list.count only lists three. I understand why this is happening, but not how to fix it so that it iterates through all 21 records.

Comment: `[@book, @recent_books, @popular_books]` is an Array, not a Hash.

Answer (score 0):

`@book_list.flatten` will produce a flat Array of 21 elements. Also, unlike `each_with_index`, `with_index` can accept the starting index, so you don't have to `index + 1`:

```
@book_list.flatten.each.with_index(1) do |book, index|
  ...
end
```